# Headset microphone stops working each reboot if webcam plugged in

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

I have a Windows 10 Dell XPS 13 9310, a Poly C5200 USB-C headset and a Razer Kiyo webcam. The headset is connected directly to my laptop, the Kiyo is connected via a USB hub.

If I reboot my machine with my webcam connected, the headset microphone won't work. To resolve this, I have to unplug my webcam, then unplug and reconnect my headset. Finally, I can plug my webcam back in again.

I've done a lot of tests to isolate the issue is my webcam. The USB hub doesn't cause these issues, nor do any of the other peripherals I attach to it.

My workaround is not too painful, but can anyone recommend further steps to debug this?

Comment: This a new problem or an old problem that recently surfaced?  If you use a Type-C USB hub and connect the headset to that instead of directly to the laptop do you have the same problem?

Comment: @Ramhound It's a new laptop and headset. I believe this issue has been occurring since I received them. I have a hub attached (to my other USB-C port), but it only has USB-A ports, so I can't experiment with that.